# cant add setSelectionRange to selected element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-input

I've selected input using "getElementById". After I want add "setSelectionRange" method to that element. But there is an error "property 'setselectionrange' does not exist on type 'htmlelement' " . What could be the problem?

```
const textfield = document.getElementById("masktextfield")
console.log(textfield)
```

that's what shows in console

[image]

now adding "setselectionrange"

```
textfield.setSelectionRange(0,0) // property 'setselectionrange' does not exist on type 'htmlelement'
```

Comment: Could it be that you have another ID called masktextfield somewhere? because it says you are trying to put a setSelectionRange on a htmlelement and not a HTMLInputElement. Meaning that it says you're trying to use that property on something that is not an input or textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const textfield = document.getElementById("masktextfield");
textfield.focus();
textfield.setSelectionRange(2, 5);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="masktextfield" value="sathish"/>
```